# What are the differences between Super Mario 64 (N64) and Super Mario 64 DS?

Tags: version-differences, super-mario-64, super-mario-64-ds

What are the differences between Super Mario 64 for the Nintendo 64 and Super Mario 64 DS for the Nintendo DS? Are they just the same game or are there any significant differences?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The DS version's main feature is a few extra playable characters with special abilities. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_64_DS) covers most of the functional differences.

However, I would like to bring attention to the main difference in my head: the DS controls are *horrible*. Since the DS doesn't have an analog stick, you are forced to use either the DPad or the stylus. Both controls are clunkier and more annoying than their 64 counterparts.

I loved the 64 version and got every star in it, and really wanted to play it again with new characters. Unfortunately, the DS controls made me unable to stand playing the DS version for more than a few levels in. It would be nice if they would rereleased the rerelease on the Wii instead so I have some chance of ever completing it. However, if you play it on a 3DS, you can use the circle pad in place of the DPad, which fixes all of those problems. On 3DS, the DS version controls just fine.

Comment: That's valuable information about the controls, @Mag!

Comment: I agree. I too wanted to play it again on the DS but the controls were just awful. Just stick to New Super Mario Bros. on the DS.

Comment: I wonder why no one ever made an analog stick add-on for the DS like they had for the original Game Boy. It would just snap around the back of the lower section and add a stick that when pressed in different directions would press the d-pad accordingly. It's not perfect, but I'm sure it would be better than just the d-pad.

Comment: You can also play with the strap (or something else to attach to your thumb) and use the bottom screen, which is the most comfortable way for me. YMMV.

Comment: So, with the 3DS analogue stick, the game controls similarly to how it did on the N64? I.e. Mario moves at different speeds, depending on how far you push the stick?

Answer (score 9):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_64), there were a few additions / changes to the DS version:

> Yoshi, Luigi, and Wario are additional playable characters, and the game features slightly altered graphics, additional stars, courses, touchscreen mini-games, and a multiplayer mode.

Answer (score 2):

DS version's graphics are way better than the N64 version. There are new characters and all have special abilities (which are listed bellow) and 30 more power stars. The only way to make the controlls better is, to buy a 3ds.

Yoshi- Fire Breath,
Mario- Float,
Luigi- Invisibility,
Wario- Metal Wario

Answer (score 1):

Yoshi, Luigi and Wario are available in the DS version. The graphics are also a bit better, there are 150 stars and those are the major changes. The not so important ones would be that Princess Peach wears her hair different and the coins in this one are octagonal. I like the DS one better because of the different characters. There were no cheep cheers in the original